# Why can't Docker find a existing package?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, protocol-buffers

I am new at using Docker so this may be obvious for some. I am running Ubuntu 18.04TLS.

I want to install the package "python3-protobuf" inside an image. I try to do this with the following line in the Dockerfile:

```
...
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        python3-protobuf \
        <some other packages to be installed>
...
```

When I run 'docker build -t myImageName', I get the message:

> E: Unable to locate package python3-protobuf

There are many packages that I am installing but this is the only one that is creating a problem for me.

I know that the package name is correct because in the terminal, when I 'apt search' for it, it is found. Additionally, in the dockerfile I do the recommended 'update' and 'install' steps. So it should be finding it. Any ideas why it does not?

Comment: Isn't that a pip package?

Comment: which base image are you using? The `python3-protobuf` package is available only for Ubuntu >=18.04. If you have a FROM image lower than Ubuntu 18.04, than the package is not found.

Comment: @Blokje5 there is a pip version as well but I'm not referring to that one.

Comment: @banuj my base image is: nvidia/cuda:8.0-cudnn5-devel-ubuntu16.04 . Does it make a difference which it is?

Comment: See https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python3-protobuf. The required package does not exist for ubuntu16.04. You should use pip package or upgrade the base image.

Comment: @banuj oh now I see. My base image is using ubuntu16.04. I kind of forgot that :P. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @banuj Good catch. Please post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@banuj answered this question.

The package "python3-protobuf" became available from Ubuntu 18.04 and onward. The base image I took is using ubuntu 16.04.

I have two way to solve this:

1. Use a base image that is with ubuntu 18.04 (or later)
2. Use pip to install the package.

I ended up using option two.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: https://thestrugglingdeveloper.medium.com/docker-apt-get-unable-to-locate-package-d8af66fd9725

In case that article becomes unavailable, I reproduce the solution below as it as:
"Solution
Execute a simple apt-get update before you execute your installation command, like apt-get install nano (yes I prefer nano) and see it being successfully being installed in the running instances of your docker container (remember this, after a container restart your editor is gone again)."